# Hard reset when copying big files - lost free space

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I was copying virtual image files via altap salamander (like total commander). When it was copying I have to hard reset PC. After start and delete succesfully copied files, there was only 37GB free space. Before copying it was 50GB.

It looks like copy of big files was allocated free space, but when I reset PC it doestn finish yet and now it looks like used space (It isnt free space).

Do you know some tool, which can find this space and delete it? I use Windows 8.1.
I try check disk but it doesnt help.

Thanks

Comment: Your image files may have been [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). The act of copying them may have expanded the "holes" in the files to occupy actual disk space. I don't know offhand how you'd revert that on windows.

Comment: I am not sure. Destiny folder is empty, sparse files should be visible, am I right?

Comment: Yes, sparse files are still files, so they're visible in directory listings. Your question doesn't say that the destination files are actually missing, just that you lost more space than expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a linux-base file explorer to do that.

if you have Ubuntu installation disk, there's a try option before installing that you can use as a live disk and use its built-in file explorer to that so.

Comment: I try ubuntu live CD with no result. I cant see files in destiny directory. So space is still full but file doesnt exists.

Comment: have you tried unchecking `Hide system files` or using `Show hidden files and folders` in your windows folder option?

Comment: Yes, and I was able to delete this folder. I thing, I am unable to get to something, who holds the space. So I probably need some tool which check all part of disk and check if it is accessable for system. If there is an part of disk mark as non-free and unaccessable, it is error and this part should be mark as editable.

Comment: So take a look [here](http://classroom.synonym.com/erase-unused-hard-drive-sectors-16124.html). this site explains how to remove unused sectors to prevent data recovery. i think it might be helpful for you.